# X-axes scaling in MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, time-series

We have a time-series data that we're plotting it using `plot` function (or any other function). I want different scaling in different time durations. Suppose we have 100 years data. In first 60 years I want plot my data (X-axes scales) in every 15 years and in end 40 years I want plot it in every 10 years. I have a yearly database. I only want show data as I mentioned.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [this discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/15002)? Are you looking for something similar?

Comment: are number of time-steps in both the scales always same?

Comment: My database scaling is year. I only want show my data as I said.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = cumsum(rand(1,100))/100; %// example data
ind1 = 10:10:60;
ind2 = 61:100;
ind2_tick = 70:10:100;
plot([ind1 ind2], data([ind1 ind2]), '-o')
set(gca, 'xtick', [ind1 ind2_tick]);
xlabel('year')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Can we change x-axes scaling in plot? In this plot the difference is 10 years.I want 10 20 ... 60 and after that 61 62.... 100.

Comment: @user2991243 See edited answer. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's true in showing data. Can we change scaling in x-axes?. In this plot difference is equal to 10. In first 60 years this is true but after that I want show in small durations(10,20,30 in x-axes of plot). Suppose that we have 100 years data. In first 60 years I want plot my data (X-axes scales) in every 15 years and in end 40 years I want plot it in every 10 year. this is more wider so we can show this in plot. I edited my question with this scaling.

Comment: So you mean that you want to use a different scale for different parts of the plot? That is a bit tricky. Matlab does not have this option by itself, but it is possible create something that looks like the scale is in homogeneous. What you need to do is to modify the "year vector". You need to give all the data a "pretend to be" year. For example sampled often may be given years `[60,62,64,68,70]`. Even if every occurency happened in year 60. then change the `XTickLabels` to the year you want it to be. This will however, make scaling the figure in matlab impossible